# Can we have a badge that can be earned by getting friends to use the site?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I would like to see a badge earned when a user clicks through to stack overflow and joins as a result of following a link you gave them. The said link would be provided by stack overflow.
Is this possible?
What are your thoughts community?

Comment: Something like `Announcer`/`Booster`/`Publicist`? Or do you mean the visitor would actually have to sign up on the site?

Comment: Yes a similar concept, but one that resulted in the user joining stack overflow

Comment: how about if you hang a url off your profile page to their user profile. So then we know who to *thank*

Comment: How would we prevent malicious users from creating a bazillion accounts to get the related badges? Looks like we could name that badge "Sock Generator".

Comment: Not having enough users is most definitely *not* an SO problem.  You ought to get a badge for helping your friends instead of them having to use SO :)

Comment: Uh........ why?

Comment: Why would we encourage people signing on because of referral bagdes? What use or worth has an account to SO if they are not posting quality questions and answers or otherwise helping the site? Just beeing here is nothing.

Comment: i guess a bade for scoring -10 in one hour is out of the question, coz if not I'm the first to achieve it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*If* we implement [some kind of mentoring program](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262292/165773) where experienced users invite a friend or colleague to join the site, and help them learn the ropes a bit - there will *most likely* be a badge for that. What you would have essentially done is brought a new contributor to the site who managed to get to around 200 rep from people other than you voting for their posts.

For simply getting someone to sign up? That feels kind of 'meh' to me. I'm completely open to anything that incentivizes current users to invite more folks that are likely to stick around and do stuff, but they'd need to actually *do* stuff before we could call it an accomplishment. We have a pretty long tail of users, I'd want such a badge to focus on bringing in more *active* people that leave a positive impact on the site.

You're thinking in the right direction, but more effort would be needed to earn the badge (and suggestions for what to call it / type it should be wouldn't hurt) if you want to try again.

Comment: A **Summoner** *Silver* badge - Invited a user who registered and gained *X* amount of rep within 90 days and visited the site *X* times?

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ that badge would incentivize serial upvoting from a guy who invited  on posts of their friend

Comment: @gnat fair enough.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ I like the idea but agree that serial upvoting could be a problem. A possible way to get around this would be to not count upvotes by the user who invited the other user: "_Invited a user who registered and visited the site X times and has a total question and answer score of X within 90 days (your own votes don't count)_"